# Unable to import wordpress xml file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

This is first time developing website using Wordpress. While importing pages and posts on localhost using wordpress import plugin, I encountered following error.

`Unable to create directory uploads. Is its parent directory writable by the server?`

I tried changing `wp-content` folder's permission to 777 -> didn't work

I tried changing ownership of `wp-content` folder to apache:apache -> didn't work

I tried manually creating `uploads` folder under `wp-content`. With this change, I was able to pass the above error, but then I got the following error.

`Sorry, there has been an error. The uploaded file could not be moved to uploads.`

What else should I try to import Wordpress xml file?

Why the Wordpress cannot create `uploads` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the web server's temp directory for PHP.if the  apache:apache has no permission on this directory,you can't move tempfile to uploads.if so,you can change the permission of the web server's temp directory.

Comment: I checked php.ini file to find out which directory I use for uploading. It was commented out so I added `upload_tmp_dir="/tmp"`, but had no luck.